# Preferred method of overriding an emacs lisp function?

Tags: emacs, overriding

I have rewritten and stand-alone tested the behaviour of an inner function invoked by one of the Emacs functions bundled with Emacs 24. What is the preferred way of incorporating - e.g. in my `init.el` - my function's behaviour overriding the bundled function?

I have followed various threads of `advice` vs `fset` etc. and am confused.

Comment: Code?  Why so cryptic if you actually have a funciton in mind?

Comment: Why does it matter what function. Its the preferred mthod of overriding any functiion I'm asking about. FWIW It's an org-mode function - org-mac-message-insert-flagged - that needs updating for my use. If update works for me then I will discuss in org forum whether its appropriate as patch for org distro. Right now, though, I need to know how to have an inner function use my EMACS lisp rather than that distributed. OK will look at advice framework.

Comment: It looks as though I need to use an _Around_Advice_ without ever using the "variable" `ad-do-it` thus overriding the original function completely.  I will try this and report back with an answer.

Comment: If you're planning to define around advice which doesn't include `ad-do-it`, you should simply be redefining the function (unless you're enabling and disabling that advice dynamically). Advice is for modifying the behaviour of the original, not for completely replacing it in all situations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@iainH You tend to get to a useful answer faster by describing what goal
you're trying to accomplish, then what you have so far.  I asked for code to
try to help you do what you want to do without having to overwrite anything.

I still don't understand why you don't just use `defun` though?  I suspect
what may happen is you use `defun` in your init file, but the original
function isn't loaded yet (see [autoload](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html)).  Some time later, you do
something to cause the file with the original definition to be loaded and your
custom function is overwritten by the original.

If this is the problem, you have three options (let's say you want to
overwrite `telnet-initial-filter` from "telnet.el"):

1. Load the file yourself before you define your own version.

   ```
   (require 'telnet)
   (defun telnet-initial-filter (proc string)
     ...)
   ```
2. Direct Emacs to load your function only after the file loads with the
   [eval-after-load](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) mechanism.

   ```
   (eval-after-load "telnet"
     '(defun telnet-initial-filter (proc string)
        ...))
   ```
3. Use advice.

Of these, 2 is best.  1 is also okay, but you have to load a file you may
never use in a session.  3 is the worst.  Anything involving `defadvice`
should be left as a last resort option.

Comment: Why is `defadvice` so bad?

Comment: In my particular case I had to explicitly `(load "org-mac-message")` before the `eval-after-load` solution worked. Thanks for the advice (sic). So I have the answer to my question _What is the preferred method of replacing [completely overriding the behaviour of] an Emacs Lisp function?_ Many thanks @event_jr

Comment: @katspaugh As @phils also infers: `defadvice` is more appropriate to embellishing existing behaviour rather than completely replacing it - as in this case. `defadvice` allows you to add behaviour _before_; _after_; and _around_ existing functionality. `defadvice` does allow you to replace behaviour but I think solution 2 above is most appropriate here.

Comment: With the "new" advising functions you can use `advice-add` to override a function: `(advice-add 'old-function :override #'my-new-function)`. You can add the advice before a function is even defined.

Comment: Still, what's so bad about `defadvice`? I'm trying to change a functions behavior: `(defvar *old-f* 'f) (defun f () (progn ... (*old-f*)))`. And whenever it runs, `emacs` says: `Symbol’s function definition is void: *old-f*`. I'm trying to change one particular case of [`python-indent--calculate-indentation`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.3/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1058-L1063) function. I'd like to understand what's wrong with [my code](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/7ba422550dc06ecd6f21cd1749fc1d94). But I think I'll try `defadvice` for now.

Answer (score 6):

Just to keep this question self-contained, here is how to do it with advice.

```
(defadvice telnet-initial-filter (around my-telnet-initial-filter-stuff act)
  "Things to do when running `telnet-initial-filter'."
  (message "Before")
  ad-do-it
  (message "After") )
```

This is obviously useful primarily if you want to wrap, not replace, an existing function (just redefine it in that case).

For much more on using advice, see [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: I sometimess use around advice to completely redefine functions. The advantage of using around advice instead of just redefining the function using `defun` is that advice also overrides any future redefinitions of the function (e.g. when the package is not loaded until after the code that redefines the function).

Answer (score 6):

There's a ["new" advice method](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) which can set up function replacements even before the original one is loaded.

```lisp
(defun something-fixed ()
  ...
  )
(advice-add 'original-function :override #'something-fixed)
```

This even works in combination with `eval-buffer` of e.g. your init file.

Answer (score 1):

I found hard to reason about `eval-after-load` + `defun`. And `defadvice` macro has complicated semantic and documentation. Instead I use advice primitives like `advice-add`:

```lisp
(defun my-vc-git-print-log (files buffer &optional shortlog start-revision limit)
   ...)

(defun my-vc-git-print-log-advice (fn &rest args)
  "Uses `my-vc-git-print-log' that adds extra `--all' to `git log'."
  (apply #'my-vc-git-print-log args))

(advice-remove 'vc-git-print-log #'my-vc-git-print-log-advice)
(advice-add 'vc-git-print-log :around #'my-vc-git-print-log-advice)
```