# How to change the behaviour of org-agenda-goto to open org-file in a new frame?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When pressing TAB (`org-agenda-goto`) in org-agenda I want to open the related org-file in a new frame instead of splitting the existing frame.

I could create a modified function of `org-agenda-goto` replacing `switch-to-buffer-other-window`  with `switch-to-buffer-other-frame` and rebinding the `TAB`-key but I assume there is a more elegant way to do so?

The quick solution would be as below modifying line 8:

```lisp
(defun sk/org-agenda-goto (&optional highlight)
  "Go to the entry at point in the corresponding Org file."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((marker (or (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker)
             (org-agenda-error)))
     (buffer (marker-buffer marker))
     (pos (marker-position marker)))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame buffer)
    (widen)
    (push-mark)
    (goto-char pos)
    (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (org-show-context 'agenda)
      (recenter (/ (window-height) 2))
      (org-back-to-heading t)
      (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (when (re-search-forward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
      (goto-char (match-beginning 4)))))
    (run-hooks 'org-agenda-after-show-hook)
    (and highlight (org-highlight (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))))
```

I assume it may be done more elegantly with `advice` but I'm not so experienced in emacs-lisp and would not know how exactly this could be achived or if using `advice` would be the right approach.

I found out in [override prefered method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717103/preferred-method-of-overriding-an-emacs-lisp-function)  are hints for using advice-add like this in order to replace the original function with my own:

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-agenda-goto :override #'sk/org-agenda-goto)
```

Comment: As I understand by using advice-add I replace the old fucntion with a new function but this takes away flexibility. It would be better to keep the old function and just replace `switch-to-buffer-other-window`with ´switch-to-buffer-other-frame`. But I am not sure if and how this can be achived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advice to temporarily redefine `switch-to-buffer-other-window` using `cl-letf`.  Assuming your on at least emacs 25.1 you can use `define-advice`, eg.

```
(define-advice org-agenda-goto (:around (orig-fn &rest args) "new-frame")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'switch-to-buffer-other-window)
             (symbol-function 'switch-to-buffer-other-frame)))
    (apply orig-fn args)))
```

In the advice `orig-fn` is a placeholder to `org-agenda-goto`.  Alternatively, you could temporarily override `display-buffer`'s function (there are a number of options you could use here -- see help for `display-buffer`), eg.

```
(define-advice org-agenda-goto (:around (orig-fn &rest args) "new-frame")
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-pop-up-frame)))
    (apply orig-fn args)))
```

Comment: So instead of just changing the obvious top level function `switch-to-buffer`  advising `display-buffer` to take another argument goes one level deeper and allows a more subtle change and even bigger variety of options. This gives a deeper insight on how the code can be modified even on a lower level.

Comment: Sort of, the second advice is just temporarily binding a value to `display-buffer-overriding-action`, not making `display-buffer` take another argument.